# How to Change ContentControl `s Content on Toggle Button IsChecked Proprrty

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, contentcontrol

Currently i am working on Changing the Content ( as image) of a container on toggle button IsChecked Proprty.
So i thought ContentControl would be a nice choice for a container. But i am not able to figure out how to achieve the result.

I created a resource of images in windows.resource

```
<Image Source="Resources/Desert.jpg" x:Key="image1"/>
    <Image Source="Resources/Koala.jpg" x:Key="image2"/>
    <Image Source="Resources/Lighthouse.jpg" x:Key="image3"/>
    <Image Source="Resources/Chrysanthemum.jpg" x:Key="image4"/>
```

So i thought to Use the above resource to change the Content Property of a ContentControl by changing the ControlTemplate proprty by using Triggers where SourceName as (ToggleButton) and TargetName as (ContentControl)  but its not working

SO how can I change the content of a ContentControl on toggleButton Ischeck property.

Edit

```
<ContentControl BorderBrush="Black" Name="cc">
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="ToggleButton" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="cc" Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource image1}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
```

I just tried as i have no idea how to do it.....

Any help are welcomed

Comment: Show the code that *is not* working, not code that *is* working.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Edited the post.
But friend i don`t have an idea to proceed.

Comment: OK, now tell us *what happens* when you run this (does it compile at all?), and what do you expect to happen. 'Doesn't work' is not informative.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma, please read through the [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the Help Center to learn how to ask better questions and therefore get better answers.

Comment: Use a `DataTrigger` in your `ContentControl.Style` that checks if `SomeCheckbox.IsChecked` is `True`, and if so sets the correct image. I have an example [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/), however it binds to the DataContext instead of to another UI element. You'll want an `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` binding instead of a normal binding to the `DataContext`

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for your answer...i`ll definitely look onto it..

Comment: @Rachel Thanks for ur answer....big fan of your blog in wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have over complicated the situation unnecessarily. You can just use an `Image` control rather than a `ContentControl`. To alternate between two `Image`s, you can simply do this with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<Image Source="Resources/Desert.jpg" x:Key="image1"/>
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Name="Button" Content="Change Image" Margin="10" />
    <Image Margin="10,0,10,10">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
Value="/YourAppName;component/Resources/Desert.jpg" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Button}" 
Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
Value="/YourAppName;component/Images/Resources/Koala.jpg" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</StackPanel>
```